# Difference between RidgeCV() and GridSearchCV()

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, linear-regression, linear-algebra

RidgeCV() also searches on a set of hyperparameters, and given a similar kernel in GridSearchCV() along with similar parameters would there be any difference in the results of the two?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RidgeCV implements cross validation for ridge regression specifically, while with GridSearchCV you can optimize parameters for any estimator, including ridge regression.